# Che differenza c'è fra "ditta" e "azienda" in italiano?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

I would like to know the proper usage of **ditta** and **azienda** and how do we differentiate between them in Italian.

Answer (score 6):

In every day speaking they can be used as synonyms, the difference stands in the legal meaning which distinguishes them clearly:

- **impresa** is the activity performed by the entrepreneur and it can be carried out among various fields;
- **azienda** is the whole set of assets organized by the entrepreneur in order to carry out activities ([art. 2555 Italian Civil Code](http://www.altalex.com/documents/news/2014/03/31/dell-azienda)) and it includes premises, furnitures, machinery, facilities, etc.;
- **ditta**, finally, is the trade name of the entrepreneur ([art. 2563 Italian Civil Code](http://www.diritto24.ilsole24ore.com/guidaAlDiritto/codici/codiceCivile/articolo/3186/art-2563-ditta.html?refresh_ce=1)), namely the name used to pursue their activity in order to draw a distinction between their company and competitors thereof.

You can more information [here](https://www.bargiornale.it/quale-e-la-differenza-tra-impresa-azienda-e-ditta/) although in Italian.

Comment: Probabilmente è un mio problema personale, ma rifarsi come fonte a Yahoo Answers non mi sembra il massimo. Questo dovrebbe essere un sito in cui si danno fonti vere e accreditate, mentre lì il primo che passa dice la sua...

Comment: Posso capire la tua posizione rispetto a Yahoo Answers, ma a supporto della risposta ci sono anche i riferimenti al Codice Civile che ho provveduto ad linkare con la spiegazione per maggiore chiarezza

Comment: Non criticavo il resto della risposta, che va benissimo (e anzi sicuramente ne sai più di me), ma solo la menzione di Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Condivido pienamente l'appunto

Answer (score 1):

The definitions that have been given are right, but sometimes "ditta" is used with a broader meaning. In everyday speaking sometimes azienda and ditta are used as synonyms. I've often heard people saying "Vado in ditta" or "In ditta abbiamo questo macchinario" meaning the building.  Probably it's not perfectly correct, but it's used.
http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=ditta
For example:
http://www.torinotoday.it/cronaca/cassoni-rubati-fiat-leini.html
http://m.ilgiornaledivicenza.it/territori/montecchio/sovizzo/infortunio-in-ditta-30enne-schiacciato-da-un-muletto-1.5786745
http://www.ilgiorno.it/lodi/cronaca/incidente-1.3218940

Comment: True, but isn't this what the very first words of abarisone's answer say?

Answer (score 0):

*Azienda* is the company: set of equipment, buildings, machines, fornitures arranged by the admin;

*Ditta* is simply the name used by the company administrator (according to the laws) to distinguish the company from the competitors.

Comment: Sicuro, @Orlok? Per il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ditta/), lo Zingarelli e altri, la “ditta” è anche l'impresa stessa, nonché la sua sede.

Comment: Come hanno evidenziato sopra l'_impresa_  è un'altra entità con un'altra definizione. La domanda riguardava la distinzione tra ditta e azienda.

Comment: Non è quello il problema, @Orlok, ma non importa.